# Using Axios how to send username in GET request

Tags: django, reactjs, react-redux, axios

React-Django application. User signs in by providing username and password through Axios `PUT`, if correct JWT and username is returned, both are stored in `sessionStorage`. User is then automatically routed to `/home` which should populate with information specific to the user.

`/home` has `componentWillMount()` that is supposed to `GET` via Axios the content for `/home` from the database. Some is static and some is relevant to the user, for example `first_name`. I'm trying to send the username along with the JWT to retrieve this information but not sure how to.

This is what I have that is working in retrieving static content like the welcome message. Just want to send `username` along to so I can add logic server-side to retrieve information for this user and send back in the response.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { ROOT_URL } from '../../config/config.json';

// Establish the different types
export const WELCOME_MESSAGE = 'welcome_message';

export function getWelcome() {

    return function(dispatch) {
        axios
            .get(
                `${ROOT_URL}/api/home/`,
                { headers: 
                    { 
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'JWT ' +  sessionStorage.getItem('token')
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({ 
                    type: WELCOME_MESSAGE,
                    payload: response.data
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Broke");
            });
    }
}
```

Worst case, I just make another function with `POST` where I know I can send this information easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to send the username in **GET** request method in **AXIOS.**
You can send the username in URL as the **query** so that at the backend you can access username from URL query 
**example:**
***${ROOT_URL}/api/home?username=rahulrana***

This is how you can achieve this through GET method.
through the query in URL is the only way to send information.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clearing that up. Starting to realize I need to understand REST better.

Comment: No Problem.Just have a look how to deal with data in rest different methods.

Comment: @sockpuppet Actually, this is just a standard API request, a RESTful request of the same type would be `/api/users/rahulrana/components/home` for instance, where `users` and `components` describe resource names, and `rahulrana` and `home` describe identifiers for each one of those resources. Rahul is correct in saying that a GET request has to pass parameters through the URI itself since the request doesn't have a body, but the parameters don't *have* to be in a query, they can be part of the URI if you choose to design your API that way.